# iOS closing experience less than stellar

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close, usability, ios-app

I tried to close a question on Meta as a duplicate using the iOS app. The experience was.... troublesome.

I followed a chain of comment and answer links to a post that I knew my starting point was a dupe of. Once there, I wanted to copy a link so I could vote to close.

However, there is no easy option to copy a link on posts. You can:

- Share -> copy, and you get a *Great question: [title] [link]* piece of text.
- Share -> open in Chrome (or open in Safari), then you can copy the link from the URL

but neither are ideal. That's issue #1.

Having obtained a link via the browser route, it's back to the original question.

To the post options: Close found, and a dialog pops up that asks me to pick the usual options, pick *duplicate*, and the dialog tells me I am *flagging*, not voting:

[image: Dupe dialog]

So that's issue #2, I am now confused; was I closing or did I pick the flag option by accident?

Pressing on, I pasted the URL, and hit 'Flag'.

*And the app crashed.*

I used the mobile web  UI to cast my close vote instead.

This was with version 0.1.28 (still the current version as of this writing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. I have found the crash you mention, and have fixed it.
2. When coming from the "close" button, the dialog will now display "vote to close" instead of "flag".
3. If you go to share -> copy a question or answer, the copied value will now only contain the URL.

These changes will be available **in version 0.1.29**

I hope these improvements make it easier for you to vote to close questions.

Comment: I'll test as soon as I have a target to work with! :-) Oh, and the new version is actually available, of course.

Comment: Confirmed fixed on 0.1.29. Thanks!