# Close vote in iOS app still says 'flag'

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close, ios-app

There was a recent bug report about the alert when you vote to close vote saying 'flag' rather than 'close'. ([link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226395/233816))

This has been fixed, but both the initial presenters, and the activity circle which pop up when you've selected a window still say 'flag' (or 'flagging'). Top right in the attached image.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for catching this. I have updated the bar button to say "Vote to Close" when appropiate, as well as the text on the activity indicator to say "Voting to Close..." instead of "Flagging...".

This change will be included in beta version 1.1.0.133.